# Using Pojo as Key in MAP unable to find Key Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Trying to use POJO in Key but unable to find match Any issue with current methodolgy
How can I solve this?

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String a[]){`enter code here`
    HashMap<model, String> hm = new HashMap<model, String>();
    //add key-value pair to hashmap
    List<model> lm=new ArrayList<>();
   lm.add(new model(1,"1"));
   lm.add(new model(2,"2"));
   hm.put(lm.get(0), "1");
    System.out.println("Start");

    if (hm.containsKey(lm.stream().filter(person->person.name.equals("1")
            &&
            person.rollNo.equals(1)).findFirst())) {
        System.out.println("hit");
    }

}
static class  model{
    private Integer rollNo;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    model   modeltemp= (model)obj;
    if (modeltemp.name.equals(name)&& modeltemp.rollNo.equals(rollNo)) {
        return true;
    }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
    public Integer getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
    public void setRollNo(Integer rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public model(Integer rollNo, String name) {
        super();
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: besides being super unclear, what is your actual question?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606447

Comment: do you understand how a HashMap key is being searched? equals AND hashcode...

Comment: By using a key that is mutable, you expose yourself to nasty bugs. Do yourself a favour and use immutable keys. For guidance, see item 17: _Minimize mutability_ in Josh Bloch's _Effective Java_, 3rd ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first problem is that you need to implement `hashCode` *and* `equals`, thus add a method to your `Model` (classes are uppercase):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getRollNo(), getName());
}
```

Then `findFirst` returns an `Optional<Model>`, not a `Model`. Since `containsKey` from `HashMap` accepts an `Object` as a parameter, this will work as a method call, but obviously nothing will be found.

You could simplify this (and make it more readable) via:

```
  Model m = list.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.name.equals("1"))
            .filter(p -> p.rollNo.equals(1))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Key not found"));

  if (hm.containsKey(m)) {
        System.out.println("hit");
  }
```

Just notice that this throws an Exception if your list does not contain this person (you could do other things as well here - up to you)

Comment: Optional equals and hashcode delegate to the non null value, so if the model class was willing to test Optional<model>, that could still work. Of course, the whole stream.filter... findfirst is just completely odd and makes it fail on top of the missing hashCode().

Comment: @user2023577 right, assuming something like this would be in place `Model modeltemp;
            if (obj instanceof Optional) {
                modeltemp = ((Optional<Model>) obj).get();
            } else {
                modeltemp = (Model) obj;
            }...` but I don't know if that would fit into the OP's model

Comment: Optional should always be a return value, never an input argument anyway.

Comment: @user2023577 well... it is used  as input in our project, so "sometimes" != "never"; though a null would be preferable in internal calls to denote a missing values I guess

Comment: Well, so who's checking the optional is not null? See, it's not helping on input. Optional is a declaration from the method returning and should never extend beyond that. Notice that Optional is not serializable also to enforce that concept.

Comment: @user2023577 agreed again, I never understood why this was prohibited, but at the same time hashCode and equals was added, basically giving me the option to add those to a Set for example. If they really wanted to do it for return types only - this should have been prohibited also

Comment: @fawad you probably just got lucky - without it there are no guarantees of what will happen

Comment: @Eugene i added just 
     'Model m = list.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.name.equals("1"))
            .filter(p -> p.rollNo.equals(1))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Key not found"));'
as per your advice but didn't  overide hascode just overidden the equals

Comment: @fawad your choice, just know that if this breaks in mysterious ways...

Comment: @Eugene thanks for sharing the answer if you could share any scenario in the current example that can break it ,that would be really helpful

Comment: @fawad are you like asking for trouble not implementing hashCode here? It's like 3 to 5 lines of code. I don't understand you

Comment: No admonition for using a mutable key? Using mutable keys for a hash map is a recipe for disaster.